# Running a specific test in a testNG group

Tags: testng

I see that I have a testNG group like

```
class TestXYZ {

    @Test(groups = "group1")
    public void test1() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test(groups = "group1")
    public void test2() {
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }   
}
```

Now if I want to run the whole group tests I can use

java -cp testjar.jar org.testng.TestNG -testjar testjar.jar -groups group1

(Assume that testjar.jar is a fat jar that has all testNG and test classes bundled together).

But I am not sure how to run test1 only from the group1 group. I tried out the -methods option, but realized that it's not for a method within a group, couldn't find any other solutions online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this approach by assigning your tests into different groups? Say, **smokeTest** and **functionTest** groups.

```
class TestXYZ {

    @Test(groups = "group1", "smokeTest")
    public void test1() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test(groups = "group1", "functionTest")
    public void test2() {
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }   
}
```

Then you can

- run **test1** only by running tests that belong to **smokeTest**.
- run **test2** only by running tests that belong to **funtionTest**.
- run both **test1** and **test2** by running tests that belong to **group1**.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, but as the number of tests increases, tagging this way won't be scalable. But glad I found some solution.

Comment: For now I will accept this solution. I did further research, but couldn't find an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is other way to run tests using a combination of regular expression and `xml` configuration file.

Say, you have four tests:

```
@test(groups={"test1"})
public void testMethodOne() {}

@test(groups={"test11"})
public void testMethodOneOne() {}

@test(groups={"test20"})
public void testMethodTwoZero() {}

@test(groups={"test21"})
public void testMethodTwoOne() {}
```

In the `xml` configuration file, you can write something like below:

```
<run>
    <include name="test1.*"/>
    <exclude name="test2.*"/>
</run>
```

this **.*** is basically a wild card, all tests that have names starting with **test1** will be executed while all tests that have names starting with **test2** will not be.

Another example will be, if you use this string `.*test.*`, you are basically searching for a test name that has this `test` string in it, a few examples are:

- 123test
- test234
- ssstestsss

This should provide more scalability than my first suggestion.